# Check if all numbers from 1 to K can be formed only using numbers from array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

my problem is the next: We have given array of N integer numbers and integer K, now we have to check is it possible to form all integer numbers from 1 to K, such that we can only use elements from the given array. We cannot use element more than once.

Here is one example: array={1,2,3,4} and K = 10, we can see that the answer is TRUE because we can form all those numbers 1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=4+1, 6=4+2, 7=4+2+1, 8=4+3+1, 9=4+3+1, 10=4+3+2+1.

And here is another example: array={1,3,4} and K = 3, we can see that we cannot form integer 2, so the answer should be FALSE.

I have found one code on internet and I've been thinking of it, but I cannot get how it works and why is it correct always.

Here is my code:

```
int n, k; cin>>n>>k;
int arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    cin>>arr[i];
}
sort(arr,arr+n);
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if(arr[i]>sum+1) return false;
    sum+=arr[i];
    if(sum>=k) return true;
}
return true;
```

Comment: i assume we cannot use an element more than once?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add that.

Comment: And we can only use addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simpler problem of Google Code Jam from 2015, link: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4244486/dashboard#s=p2&a=2

Analysis: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4244486/dashboard#s=a&a=2

The logic behind that algorithm is:

We iterate from the smallest number while maintaining an integer `sum`. `sum` means that we can produce all numbers from `0 to sum`.

When we can make numbers from `0 to sum`, and now encounter a new number, say `arr[2]`, it is obvious that we can create all the numbers from `sum` to `sum + arr[2]` (since we can create all numbers from `0 to sum`, we can simply add `arr[2]` to any of those smaller sums to make any number between `sum` and `sum + arr[2]`.

If there's any gap, (indicated by this line of code `if(arr[i]>sum+1) return false;`) it means no combination of items between arr[0] and arr[i-1] could add up to sum+1, even with the help of `arr[i]`. Case in point, `arr[] = {1,3,4}. k = 3`.

After first iteration, we can make any number from `0 to 1`.
On the second iteration, which is `arr[1] = 3`, we notice there's a gap between `sum and arr[i]`, and that means no matter how you add those numbers, we can't fill the gap needed, hence the function returns false.

Comment: You have this bit "it means no number between 0 and sum could make sum". May I suggest to rewrite it to "it means no combination of items between arr[0] and arr[i-1] could add up to sum+1, even with the help of arr[i]"?

Comment: Also you could argument a bit more as to *why* no combination could add up to `sum + 1`. It's may not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: I would say that's pretty clear though. When the sum of `arr[0]..arr[i-1] +1` is smaller than `arr[i]`, it means that the smallest number you can get with the help of arr[i] is `arr[i]` (summing 0 + arr[i]), which is bigger than sum + 1.